# Nested Single Table Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance

I'm facing an issue with an object model and Hibernate. I would like the entire model to be stored as a single table.

I have tried the the following, but when I ask Hibernate to generate the SQL create files, it creates 3 tables instead of only 1. The class hierarchy might seem odd, but it is taken out of context of course :)

Attempt 1:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CATEGORY", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length  = 10)
@Table(name = "the_table")
public abstract class A {}

@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
public abstract class B extends A {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "X")
public class X extends B {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Y")
public class Y extends B {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Z")
public class Z extends B {}
```

Attempt 2:
We are getting there, not it creates 1 table, but there is no discriminator column generated. Can anybody spot the error?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CATEGORY", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length  = 10)
@DiscriminatorFormula(value = "CATEGORY || '_' || TYPE")
@Table(name = "the_table")
public abstract class A {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
public abstract class B extends A {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_X")
public class X extends B {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_Y")
public class Y extends B {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_Z")
public class Z extends B {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove @MappedSuperclass and try.  Also you can't have @Inheritance tag twice in a single hierarchy - only one will be used.

If you want to use multiple columns as discriminator use the @DiscriminatorFormula

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorForumula("CATEGORY || '_' || TYPE")
public abstract class A 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_X")
public class X extends A {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_Y")
public class Y extends A {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B_Z")
public class Z extends A {}
```

Comment: I need the MappedSuperClass in order to map the fields to the table. I have tried to remove the Inheritance annotation from class B but without luck.

Comment: You should use @Entity instead. I have updated the answer with a mapping that I think will work.

Comment: You need to remove the DiscriminatorColumns from both the A and B. Only retain the DiscriminatorFormula.  The columns (Category & Type) will not be included in the generated schema. If you want that just add ordinary fields with @Column mapping to the class A.